# Best way to group by category a list of products | Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm, grouping

I'm trying to find the best way to group by category and iterate products in O (n) to get some insights from the categories.

I have the sample data:

```
[
    {
        "code": 25754,
        "description": "ADAPTADOR BLUETOOH USB RECEPTOR DE AUDIO P2",
        "price": 5.0,
        "stock": 10,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Adapters"
        }
    },
    {
        "code": 20212,
        "description": "ADAPTADOR CONECTOR HDMI FEMEA L / FEMEA",
        "price": 2.8,
        "stock": 20,
        "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Eletronics"
        }
    },
]
```

I need to invert the relationship, having a list of categories with corresponding products, and for that i wrote this solution

```
function group_by_categories(products) {
    const categories = {}

    for (const product of products) {
        const { category, ...cleanedProduct } = product
        categories[category.id] = categories[category.id] || category
        categories[category.id].products = categories[category.id].products || []
        categories[category.id].products.push(cleanedProduct)
    }

    return Object.values(categories)
}

// returns

[
  { id: 1, name: 'Adapters', products: [ [Object] ] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Eletronics', products: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

But I am struggling in two things.

1. Is it the best way to reverse the relationship? How can I replicate this in another language like C, where I have no objects to use as unique keys?
2. Once you have this type of data, the only way to iterate categories and products (see how many items a category has, for example) is in O (n²)?

I appreciate all the help, even if you can only answer one question. Also, sorry for my bad English, I'm trying to be as clear as possible here.

Comment: You should limit your question to one question. The question *"Is it the best way to reverse the relationship?"* is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The question *" How can I replicate this in another language"* is too broad. You should be specific about the target language and show your work and where you are stuck. The question about time complexity would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 issues. 1) Use the code/id as keys instead, 2) Use sets instead of arrays, and 3) use an appropriate data structure to avoid duplicating work that you've already done.

1. You really just want to map the connections not all the data. I believe code is probably unique to the product, so that is your key. Your category id is also likely unique, so you only need to consider that. The mapping structures should only concern themselves with the minimal amount of unique data. This may increase performance a fair bit as well as the amount of data that get's copied is probably 1/10 to 1/100 of yours in terms of # of characters (of course translating that exactly to time saved is difficult). Of course, that's a minor point compared to the O(N^2) performance, but just that would likely speed things up by a bit by that alone.
2. You should be using sets as well as the hash (object). Idea here is `O(1)` lookup, `O(1)` size check, `O(1)` inclusion test (IE: Does the category X have code Y in it?), and `O(1)` mapping back to the original data (code Y is a product with this information).

The other key thing is you really just want to map the connections not all the data. I believe code is probably unique to the product, so that is your key. Your category mapping structure should only concern itself with the minimal amount of unique data (this will increase performance by a lot as well).

Keep in mind, if you have access to an actual database that is probably the more ideal solution, 95% or so of the time once you start wanting to do more complex queries. I would say you almost certainly should be using one, there's probably a database that will suit your needs.

That being said, what you need is this if you don't need to go too far with your queries. It looks like you need to answer these three questions:

- Given the code, what is the record (sample data)? This is just a simple `code:product` object. IE: `{25754: {code: ..., price: ..., stock: ..., ...}, {20212: {code: ..., price: ..., stock: ..., ...}}`
- Given a category, what are the codes in that category? In this case you have a `category_id:set(codes)` lookup. Very important that you add codes to a set and not a list/array. Sets have `O(1)` to add/delete/inclusion, while lists/arrays have `O(1)` add, `O(N)` delete and `O(N)` inclusion check.
- Given a category, how many are in that category? This is just a `data[category].size` check (length instead of size in some languages).

Main thing is to use dictionaries and sets for performance.

Time to build the lookups is likely `O(P)` where `P` is the total number products. Performance for the queries should be `O(1)` for each one you need to do.

To avoid `O(N^2)` performance the lookup should only be calculated once. Should you need to add/remove products from categories, you should adjust the lookup itself and not rebuild it every time. This may mean storing it in a database, building when you first run the app and keeping it in memory, or if the # of products isn't too much, building it at each request (by only using the minimal amount of data to build it, it may be more practical). Generally speaking, even with 1000 products, it should take probably milliseconds to build the category lookup and iterate over them.

Basically your category code should look like his after you've written out the methods.

```
...
category_lookup = build_category_lookup() # O(P)
product_lookup = build_product_lookup() # O(P)
...
products_for_category = product_lookup[category_id] # O(1)
products_count = products_for_category.length # O(1) | C: sizeof(products_for_category)
...
```

(Mostly code in ruby these days, so `snake_case`)